# How to write minimal Slack script without a server?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I joined a Slack team and now I want to play with the bots there. But there seem to be lots of different ways and they all involve some server with API.

Isn't there an easy way to write a script (is that a bot) for end users? I write a file, load it into the slack app and it works?

My first idea (just to try it out) was to respond to certain keywords automatically from my own account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are four types of custom Slack integrations:

- Incoming webhooks: your code sends an HTTP POST to Slack to post a message
- Custom slash commands: Slack sends your code an HTTP POST when someone says `/<whatever>`
- Outgoing webhooks: roughly the same as slash commands, but they can respond to any word at the beginning of a message
- Bot users: your code connects to Slack via a WebSocket and sends and receives events

In all of these cases, you need code running somewhere to actually do the work. (In the case of the bot, that code can run anywhere with network connectivity. In the other cases, you'll need a server that's listening on the internet for incoming HTTP/HTTPS requests.)

Slack itself never hosts/runs custom code. I'd say https://beepboophq.com/ is the closest thing to what you're looking for, since they provide hosting specifically for Slack bots.

Another option for things like slash commands is https://www.webscript.io (which I own). E.g., here's the entirety of a slash command running on Webscript that flips a coin:

```
return {
    response_type = 'in_channel',
    text = (math.random(2) == 1 and 'Heads!' or 'Tails!')
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! As far as I can see, all four methods need some setup from the team admin?

Comment: It depends how your team is set up... I believe that by default anyone can add a custom integration, but admins can also lock things down so only they can add integrations. Try heading to https://my.slack.com/apps/manage/custom-integrations to see what you can do from there.

Comment: https://beepboophq.com/ now appears to be a NSFW dating site.

Comment: Would it be possible to use `data:` URL or something similar as a way to return static responses without a call to a server?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something really basic, you may consider this service

https://hook.io/

you can set up a webhook there using the provided url + you token (you can pass it as env variable) and code simple logic

I hope it helps

Comment: thanks, but this is still sending company data somewhere outside of slack, so hard to get it approved :(

Comment: Please add all information to your answer instead of linking to external ressources

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty of solutions for that. 
You can use premade solutions like:

- https://hook.io
- https://www.zapier.com
- https://www.skriptex.io (disclaimer: that's my app)

Or you can setup a hubot instance, and host it by yourself.

Their API is also good, and you can just create a Slack app, bind it to some commands, and it will interact with one of your servers.

Comment: Please add all information to your answer instead of linking to external ressources